# .gitignore not on local server but shows on Git Repository

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, gitignore

In my local folders the `.gitignore` does not show up (like I was told it would Learning Ruby on Rails Tutorial), so I made one using Sublime Text. But when I uploaded the files to Git, suddenly it appeared. Now I have two `.gitignore`s on Git, but still only 1 shows in local files. Can anyone explain how to resolve this difference?

Screenshot: [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.gitignore` is a `dot` file which implies that it's hidden file.  To list all the files including hidden files in the current directory issue the following command in your terminal:

```
$ ls -al
```

You don't have two `.gitignore`s, you have one without the `dot` prefix and the other with `dot` prefix.  You should add the difference of `gitignore` and `.gitignore` to `.gitignore` (the one with the `dot` prefix) then safely remove the `gitignore`(the one without `dot`).

Answer (score 0):

This is because . files are hidden. This called [dot files](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot-file).

If you are on Linux or Mac just use `ls -la` to show all files.
Or on Windows `dir` should do the same.